# Php Session start in a upload photo to save in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload, photo

I dont why this doesn´t work, when i upload a photo with this code the image and the caption apears in my database, but the usuario_id and usuario_nombre doesn`t appear in my database, someone know why?

```
<?php
include('acceso_db.php');
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]    ["name"]);

$location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$caption=$_POST['caption'];
$my_id = $_SESSION['usuario_id'];
$nick = $_SESSION["usuario_nombre"];

$save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (`usuario_id`, `usuario_nombre`, `location`,    `caption`) VALUES ('$my_id','$nick','$location','$caption')");
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();                 
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning** You're applicaiton is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and all of your data could be completely extracted.

Comment: try to check if it exist in session ? like echo both fileds before inserting the data

Comment: **`session_start()`** (*is missing*)

Comment: I checked and the session exist. i dont know if the problem is that i put the code in a wrong place.

Comment: session_start() is in my index.php

Comment: @true thanks i have to solve that part! :S

Comment: do var_dump on $_SESSION... and try it with session_start at top to make sure.

Comment: Thanks, session_start() was the solution